# What does “the 32nd” refer to?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

I’ve been playing Outer Worlds and while in Edgewater, I did a quest for Vicar Max and he began to make a case for why I should allow him to join my ship crew. One of his arguments was that he used to be “quite the 32nd”

[image: “quite the 32nd”]

and left many an opponent bleeding in the field.

My friend and I have tried searching what this could possibly mean, but googling “what does 32nd mean” just gives me results explaining that 32nd describes the 32nd item in a sequence.

Does anyone know what Vicar Max’s statement is in reference to?

Comment: I assume it's a reference to his tossball experience, though I don't know what holding the 32nd position in a tossball team entails.

Comment: I agree with RedRiderX here. It's probably a position number, like how 1 is pitcher and 2 is catcher in baseball. 32nd is probably some variation on position number.

Comment: @RedRiderX I think you guys are right. I was pretty sleepy and I didn’t make the connection to his previous dialogue about tossball, and instead was thinking it was something shadier, like a codename for something, hahaha. If one of you wants to post an answer about this, I’d accept it, but if you could find any information about what specifically being a 32nd entails, that would be even better!

Comment: The way he says "32nd back" out loud, like it's one concept, strongly implies it's a tossball position. I'll hold off answering in case there's a better description somewhere in the game though.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, it reveals that tossball teams have at least 32 players per team. It also implies that its more than just a player count, but rather than "the 32nd" entails a particular function in the game (similar to "quarterback" or "keeper").

So far, I haven't come across any specifics on tossball, other than the stick looking like a lacrosse stick.